# Consulta bloque Try Catch NO ejecuta el bloque catch

Tags: c#, sql

Buenas tengo el siguiente codigo para consultar y llenar un DataGridView con la consulta pero lo que trato es que si el dato que usuario indica como filtro no coincide con algun registro de BD me ejecute el bloque Catch pero no lo hace

```
try
        {
            cn.Open();
            string sql = "SELECT DISTINCT cabeza.Identificacion, cabeza.Id_solicitud as #Solicitud, cabeza.Fecha,cabeza.Estatus,detalle.Id_producto,detalle.Cantidad FROM Tab_solicitud_mercancia_cabeza AS cabeza INNER JOIN Tab_solicitud_mercancia_detalle AS detalle ON cabeza.Id_solicitud = detalle.Id_producto WHERE cabeza.Id_solicitud = '" + txtidsolicitud.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            dtgv.DataSource = dt;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DialogResult respuesta;
            respuesta = MessageBox.Show("El dato ingresado no coincide con ningun registro. ¿Desea consultar el listado completo de solicitudes?", "Error En Consulta", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
            if (respuesta == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                Consultasolicitudmercancia frm = new Consultasolicitudmercancia();
                frm.enviado += new Consultasolicitudmercancia.enviar(ejecutar);
                frm.Show();

            }
            else
            {
                if (respuesta == DialogResult.No)
                {
                    txtidsolicitud.Clear();
                    txtidsolicitud.Select();
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            cn.Close();
        }
```

Comment: no tiene mucha logica lo que pedis. para que querrias lanzar una excepcion (que es lo que se necesita para ir al catch), si con hacer un if y controlar la cantidad de registros resultantes te alcanza? y lo peor, es que para lanzar la excepcion, deberias hacer ese if igual.

Comment: Lo que sucede es que el catch se activa cuando ocurre una excepcion no controlada por el usuario, es decir cuando hay un error en el código, cuando no se pudo concectar con la base, cuando la consulta está mal, en tu caso tu consulta se ejecuta bien, sin errores, lo que necesitas hacer es un if donde identifiques si el resultado de la consulta tiene filas de lo contrario podrias aplicar tu mensaje de sin resultados.

Comment: @M.Gress Entiendo, bien eso de controlar si encontro filas lo se hacer pero solo cuando uso un DataReader pero en este caso no lo utilizo

Comment: y para eso existe la documentacion de datatable.. que dice que tiene una propiedad rows.. y como si fuera casualidad.. se puede recorrer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se programa ante un error cuando puedes validar si el datatable tiene o no registros

Analiza este codigo para ver como lograrlo

```
cn.Open();
string sql = @"SELECT DISTINCT cabeza.Identificacion, cabeza.Id_solicitud as #Solicitud, 
                cabeza.Fecha,cabeza.Estatus,detalle.Id_producto,detalle.Cantidad 
                FROM Tab_solicitud_mercancia_cabeza AS cabeza 
                INNER JOIN Tab_solicitud_mercancia_detalle AS detalle ON cabeza.Id_solicitud = detalle.Id_producto 
                WHERE cabeza.Id_solicitud = @id";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txtidsolicitud.Text);

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);

if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    dtgv.DataSource = dt;
    return;
}

var respuesta = MessageBox.Show("El dato ingresado no coincide con ningun registro. ¿Desea consultar el listado completo de solicitudes?", "Error En Consulta", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
if (respuesta == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    Consultasolicitudmercancia frm = new Consultasolicitudmercancia();
    frm.enviado += new Consultasolicitudmercancia.enviar(ejecutar);
    frm.Show();
}
else
{
    txtidsolicitud.Clear();
    txtidsolicitud.Select();
}
```

Ademas es importante usar parametros, no se concatena en el string el valor que quieres filtrar

Comment: Tutini, no veo ningún inconveniente en usar una sentencia sql con la condición insertada en la cadena o usar un parámetro. Ambos dos funcionan correctamente